# calculate all projective modules over certain matrix ring

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory

Let A be the matrix algebra over field $k$ with elements of the form

\begin{bmatrix}
a & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
b & c & 0 & 0 \\
d & 0 & e & 0 \\
f & 0 & g & h
\end{bmatrix}

for $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h\in k$.

I want to determine all the projective and injective module over it.
I have the consequence that all the indecomposable direct summand of A as A-module are all the indecomposable projective modules, but how to calculate it explicitly .
I have determined $rad(A)$, the Jacobson radical, in the previous question.

Comment: The answer about what the projective or injective modules look like will probably also depend on if you are talking about left modules or right modules. Can you explain if you are interested in both or just one side?

Comment: The summands aren't hard to find right: you just look for idempotents. For starters the things on the diagonal would be $0$ or $1$, and from there you can narrow it down to indecomposable ones.